# Stop DIV scrolling once it reaches the footer (another DIV)

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I have a "back to top" button that appears when the user scrolls down the page.
With some help I have managed to implement these functions in the code below: 
**fade in** at certain point after scrolling down, **animated scroll** back to top and animated scrolling to all href="#" links of the page.

```
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash,
    $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 800, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
});

var $win = $(window);

$win.scroll(function () {

    if ($win.scrollTop() > 300) {
        b.fadeIn();
        console.log("fadding in")
    } 
    else {
        b.fadeOut();
    }
  });

});
```

Here is a working exsample: http://jsfiddle.net/q8DUC/8/

My problem is that the button scrolls into the footer of the page...
Basically the "back to top" should stop 30px above the "footer" DIV. 
But I can't find a way to accomplish that. I've looked around but haven't found anything that worked with the existing code.

Thanks for any help or suggestions!

**UPDATE:**

Got a bit further: http://jsfiddle.net/q8DUC/20/ 
Just don't know how I can avoid the jumping of the button!
Is there a way to stick the button to the bottom instead the top:0???

As always THANKS for every suggestion or help!

Comment: anyone with an idea/ suggestion or a piece of code!?!?

Answer (score 4):

I think you could get the location of the footer and add it to your conditional, which checks if the button should be displayed:

```
// dynamically get the position of the footer
var FOOTER_POSITION = someNumber;
// i THINK something like var FOOTER_POSITION = $('#T4').position().top; could work

if (300 < $win.scrollTop() && $win.scrollTop() < FOOTER_POSITION) {
```

---

Sorry, I read your question wrong, since you are using fixed positioning for your button you could implement something like:

1. get the height of the footer + 30px
2. Get a location of the footer in relation to the document, based on your fiddle ~2000px (FOOTER_START)
3. if the location of the top of the window is > 300 AND it is greater than (FOOTER_START) change `#back-top` `bottom` property to height of your footer

Comment: Thanks - Its a very nice workaround to let the button disappear as soon as it hits the footer. but it kinda misses the idea of a "back to top" button if it disappears. I would need it to stop/ become static above the footer so that the customer can use it to scroll back to the top. Any suggestions how to accomplish that?

Comment: @user2899161, sorry mis read your question, updated with some logic to help solve your problem!

Comment: Thanks a lot @dm03514! 
I do understand the logic behind it. But to be honest I'm like a beginner, didn't deal with this until last week - so I do not have the skills to get the logic into a code! Also the button is supposed to work on pages with different length. Your help would be highly appreciated..
Thx!

Comment: Hey mate! 
I really need your help with this one. I tried everything to no avail. I can't get the code to work... Any chance you could help me out here and extend the code above? Many thanks!

Comment: not getting done... 
I'm lost. Guess it will have to work with scrolling into the footer area. @dm03514 Thanks a lot for your input and help anyway!